# How do I use sqlalchemy dict to store an array of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

For sake of efficiency, it is faster to store an array of values in a table column instead of having a linking table. The table is Customer_Orders and the column is the product_name_and_quantity. The only time this data will be accessed is all at once without anything being modified.

I am essentially storing a list of these tuples. Previously I tried storing a 2 dimensional array of strings to represent this. Example: [['computers', '1'], ['smart phones', '1']

Does any of this make sense, is this a stupid way to store things? If not, can I create a dict with a list in it? The problem with the 2 dimensional array of strings is not really necessary since position doesn't matter.

Comment: What is your database platform?  For example, if you are using postgresql then array/hstore/json types will be readily available.

Comment: Yes it is postgresql, I currently use an array, but does using a dict with json type make sense?

Comment: I would use `JSONB` and store a dict `{'computers': 1, 'smart phones': 1}` in such case.